# Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform

Tags: groovy, soapui, spock

I am trying to use a different location for external jar in soapUI. I updated the soapUI batch file by adding the below line.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.libraries="C:\Program Files\Groovy\Groovy-2.1.6\lib"
```

Now when i open soapUI and try to create an activexobject using scriptom(see below)

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*
def tdc = new ActiveXObject ('TDApiOle80.TDConnection')
```

I get the following error, the error seems weird because i know i am using groovy 2.1.6 as you can see from the path.

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Groovy/Groovy-2.1.6/lib/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0-20120930.020057-22.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation because of exception org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 0.7.0-groovy-2.0 is not compatible with Groovy 1.8.0. For more information, see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org Spock location: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Groovy/Groovy-2.1.6/lib/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0-20120930.020057-22.jar Groovy location: file:/C:/Program%20Files/SmartBear/soapUI-Pro-4.5.2/lib/groovy-all-1.8.0.jar 1 error

Does anyone know why i am getting this error and what i can do to fix it?

Comment: Is SoapUI running Groovy 2.1.6 as well, or do they run with a bundled Groovy 1.8.0?

Comment: I just thought of the same thing and soapUI is running 1.8.0. Should i just find the spock compatible to version 1.8.0 and replace it with what i have? I am not sure if there are other jars which have such a compatibility problem.

Comment: Indeed it depends on 1.8.0. `C:/Program%20Files/SmartBear/soapUI-Pro-4.5.2/lib/groovy-all-1.8.0.jar` last line of the error. Replace it with corresponding 2.1.6 jar or downgrade spock, whichever is feasible. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe SoapUI (at least 4.5.1) is bundled with Groovy 1.8.0

[At least is was back in May this year (2013)](https://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=18919)

You could try the suggestion posted on the page to upgrade, or I guess you're stuck with 1.8.0 functionality (and the non-2.0 spock dependency)

Comment: great minds think alike :) i was going to ask you guys if i should replace the groovy-all-1.8.0.jar with groovy-all-2.1.6.jar. The only problem is i require an admin everytime i need to add/remove any jar from soapUI(its in program files and i do not have access). Is there someway i can make soapUI use groovy-all-2.1.6.jar located at another location instead of groovy-all-1.8.0.jar?

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana I'm not sure, but I doubt it